# How to display the number of rows to the component side RSyntaxTextArea

Tags: java, rsyntaxtextarea

How to display the number of lines next to the component -> RSyntaxTextArea

The code below works, but I need to use the specific component in place of my frame, when I do this, the lines next to disappear.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package br.com.flp.entidades;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextArea;
import org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.SyntaxConstants;
import org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextScrollPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Filipe
 */
public class TextEditorRSyntax extends JFrame {

    public TextEditorRSyntax() {

        JPanel cp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea(20, 60);
        textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_SQL);
        textArea.setCodeFoldingEnabled(true);
        RTextScrollPane sp = new RTextScrollPane(textArea);
        cp.add(sp);

         Color azulClaro =  Color.decode("#E0EEEE");
        textArea.setCurrentLineHighlightColor(azulClaro);
        setContentPane(cp);
        setTitle("Text Editor Demo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Start all Swing applications on the EDT.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TextEditorRSyntax().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy lad, The [documentation](http://javadoc.fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/org/fife/ui/rtextarea/RTextScrollPane.html) is your friend

```
sp.setLineNumbersEnabled(true);
```